# Cannot change to different windows using window.location.href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to re-direct my code to another page but for some reason It wont allow me too. I have the exact page name but it will not re-direct to that page or any page for that matter. My code is dependant on a user select a radio button that displays either yes or no. Please advise on what my errors are. Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function idForm()
{

if(document.getElementById('No').checked) {

alert("Please book a meeting room, before organising catering.");

}

if (document.getElementById('Yes').checked)
{

window.location.href = "homePage.php";


}


 }




</script>

<body>
<div id=""> <img src="" alt="" style="">
</div> 
<div class="verify" style="margin:0 auto;">
<form name="form1" action="" onsubmit="idForm()" method="post">
<!-- Booking Filter -->

 <h1>HAVE YOU BOOKED A MEETING ROOM PRIOR TO ORGANISING CATERING?</h1>

 <input type="radio" id="Yes" name="agree" value="Yes"> Yes
 <input type="radio" id="No" name="agree" value="No"> No<br> <br> <br>
 <input type="submit" class="space" name="Submit" value="Submit"> 

 </form>
</div>
```

Comment: you should check the console to see if there any errors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`window.location.href` is a property not a method. just assign it.

```
window.location.href = "homePage.php";
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work either. Am I missing something?

Comment: In the console it give me the informational message HTML 1300 Navigation Occurred and shows that it is navigating to homePage.php but nothing happens.

Comment: check the console for errors. do an alert of something to make sure your conditional is being hit.

Comment: are you in an iframe?

Comment: No iframe at all and I have already checked to see if my conditional is being hit it does if I paste the same alert as the "no" check.

Comment: then you will have to show more code. the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: @Alex - put your script tag inside the body tag at the bottom, right before the closing `</body>` and that should fix it.

Comment: @ your mum - Still no luck! Do you mean putting the whole start and end script tag with the code inside it just above the boy tag?

Comment: Just did exactly that no luck sorry!

Comment: ok, i tried it myself and realised what the problem is. you have to return false on form submit otherwise the form will just submit back to the same page. try this. if this helps please hit the checkmark by my answer :) http://pastebin.com/RHFAaWcT - note: added "return" in the form onsubmit attribute, added "return false" to the function. @Alex